# In Android, if both mobile and wifi networks are available, which one is used?

Tags: android

In my application users have the option to choose whether the app should make network requests only if WiFi network is available.

What if WiFi is available but also Mobile network is available.
Which one will Android use and is there a guarantee for it?

Comment: Depends on how the device is configured.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be the one who gives more info. Sometimes wifi it's not too accurate, and the same occurs with mobile network.

Comment: Gerald is correct.  Most devices will prefer wifi over mobile, but the user can change this, and some devices/providers will attempt to use both simultaneously to boost throughput -- e.g. when loading a web page, the device may use both wifi and mobile to download images in parallel.

Comment: So, if I want to make 100% sure that the user will not be billed, I have to only make requests if Mobile network is explicitly off and WiFi is on, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally depended on device how its ROM is configured. Priority is set in some of the phones. Some of the old device which do not have priorities use the network which is latest connected.

There are many apps available to use both connection simultaneously, but the primary requirement for that is **the phone must be rooted.**

[image]

Apps are also available that notifies user to switch network when multiple connections are available.

Comment: So, if I want to make 100% sure that the user will not be billed, I have to only make requests if Mobile network is explicitly off and WiFi is on, correct?

Comment: Even Wifi is also not free, generally for requests developer only checks for Internet connection.

Comment: Hi @ArthTilva , you have mentioned about apps which uses both connections simultaneously. Even i have a requirement which says to do the same. can you please help me with how it can be done? how a device can be made to use data services over LTE and WiFi simultaneously?